# Illustrate different kind of states in tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I am trying to draw a statemachine, in which some states are associated to one application, and the other one to another one.. I want to illustrate in my tikz drawing, by using different color but can't seem to make it work..

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}

% ------- Enable UTF8 characters ------- %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,shadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
            semithick]
            \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=black,draw=none,text=white]
            \tikzstyle{every sub}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]
            \node[state] (A)              {State i};
            \node (middle) [right = 1.5 cm of A] {h};
            \node[state] (B) [right = 3 cm of A] {State j};
            \node[sub] (i_1) [above = 1cm of middle ] {$i_1$};

            \path (A) edge [bend left]  node {$P_{ij}$} (B)
                  (B) edge [bend left] node {$P_{ji}$} (A)
                  (A) edge [loop above] node {$P_{ii}$} (A)             
                  (B) edge [loop above] node {$P_{jj}$} (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}        
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What i thought would work is to add a local

```
\tikzstyle{every sub}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]
```

Which i could use when i wan't to draw states associated with the other application, but it seems like tikz does not like it, why though?

Comment: Use `\tikzstyle{sub}` instead of `\tikzstyle{every sub}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}

% ------- Enable UTF8 characters ------- %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}

\usepackage[floats,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
    shorten > = 1pt,
            > = Stealth,
                semithick,
 state/.style = {circle, fill=#1, draw=none,
                 inner sep=1mm, text=white},
 state/.default = black
                        ]
\node (A) [state]               {State i};
\node (M) [right=of A]          {h};
\node (B) [state, right=of M]   {State j};
\node (I) [state=red,above=of M]{$i_1$};
%
\path[->]   (A) edge [bend left,  "$P_{ij}$"]   (B)
            (B) edge [bend left,  "$P_{ji}$"]   (A)
            (A) edge [loop above, "$P_{ii}$"]   (A)
            (B) edge [loop above, "$P_{jj}$"]   (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

in *mwe* i preserve from yours only for this picture relevant libraries. note: `\tikstyle` is depreciate `tikz` syntax. instead it use `\tikzset{...} or define`tikzpicture` elements style as its options as is done in *mwe* above.